# How to fade in part of a sentence?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fadein

I'm trying to make the quotes at the beginning and end of a sentence fade in when someone clicks on a button. How can I make only the quotation marks to fade in instead of the whole sentence?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly it would look something like this (using jquery):

```html
<span class="quote">"</span><span class="content">The rest of your sentence</span><span class="quote">"</span>
<button id="button">
Click this
</button>
```

```
$('#button').click(evt => {
    $('.quote').fadeIn()
});
```

```css
.quote {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: that's it. thank you very much